The type name 'ProtectionLevel' could not be found in the namespace System.Net.Security
In our project we need to implement a SOAP client to communicate with our client. After generating the client with their .wsdl, we keep getting the error:

The type name 'ProtectionLevel' could not be found in the namespace
'System.Net.Security'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
'System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0.

The error occurs on attributes that are placed throughout. For example here:
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false, ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
    public partial class getAnomalyReportRequest
    {
                [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="xxx", ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None)]
        public Ict.EnergyNxt.Tso.Client.AcknowledgementResponse.MessageAddressing MessageAddressing;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="xxx", ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign, Order=0)]
        public Ict.EnergyNxt.Tso.Client.AcknowledgementResponse.GetMessageRequest getMessageRequest;

To be clear, the ENUM ProtectionLevel.Sign is found and not a problem.
The error occurs on Protectionlevel=. Which is odd, because when looking in the decompiled MessageContractAttribute, Protectionlevel is actually present (and showing 'System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0').
Our project is running target framework net8.0. We've included the package System.Net.Security in it's latest version 4.3.2. For testing purposes we've also tried including other .net. Security packages  (which shouldn't be needed) in their latest versions.
Any thoughts on the possible cause?

Finally we've found some direction: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3386
It seems that ProtectionLevel is not exposed in .NET Core contract and thus not accessible, as it used to be in .NET Framework.

Can you use full name(System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel) in place of type ProtectionLevel and check.

Yes we did try including a using for System.Net.Security as well as explicitly add it, without succes.

Hi, please use the comment section to request additional information. Only use answer for answers.
